# Page event definition Field Completed not found

Tags: wffm

Sitecore 8.2 Update 4

When I save a WFFM form, I get the error:

```
Page event definition Field Completed not found, page URL /other/contact-us/general-inquiries
```

I seem to get it once per field on the form (That makes sense). The event Field Completed does exist in the database.

**UPDATE**

This is happening in CM and CD. I updated my above statement that it was CD only.

The client does not have Analytics as part of their license, if that is a factor.